# Как получить Bitmap из другого Bitmap и цвета?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-canvas

Программа выводит изображение на экран при помощи объекта **Canvas**.В папке **drawable** находится png-картинка. По имени картинки **bitmapName** я получаю **Bitmap** с помощью такого кода

```
    int resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(bitmapName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resID);
```

Я использую метод **drawBitmap()** для вывода полученного **Bitmap** на экран.
Проблема в том, что объект, на который наложена эта картинка используется в программе довольно часто и картинка должна иметь разные оттенки в зависимости от логики. Изображение имеет то жёлтый, то зелёный, и т.д. оттенки. Причем оттенков достаточно **МНОГО**. Самый простой способ это сделать просто создать эти изображения заранее и загрузить в память. Но загрузка большого количества картинок сильно увеличит размер приложения, а мне этого не хотелось бы. Я в фотошопе попробовал такой вариант. Поверх изображения наложил слой и залил сплошным цветом. Понизил непрозрачность этого слоя. В результате получилась картинка такая как мне нужна. Поэтому такой вопрос: как создать **Bitmap** из другого готового **Bitmap** и какого-то цвета с прозрачностью. Мне нужен метод в который я посылаю **Bitmap**, цвет, уровень прозрачности; и получаю из него готовый **Bitmap** изменённого оттенка. Подскажите, как мне добиться подобного результата? Как наложить цвет на **Bitmap**?

Comment: Может, делать background с нужным оттенком у родительского компонента? А поверх накладывать полупрозрачный bitmap

Comment: @ DrMcSheen, не совсем понял. Что изменится, если я поменяю местами картинку и цвет?

Comment: Полупрозрачный bitmap размещать внутри LinearLayout у которого задан цвет как background

Comment: @ DrMcSheen, дело в том, что у меня в программе вообще нет LinearLayout. В учебных целях пишу игровую программу. На экране несколько десятков объектов появляются, перемещаются, исчезают. Каждый объект имеет свою картинку, которую программа выводит на экран в координатах, которые хранятся в самом объекте. Каждый объект может иметь свой собственный оттенок. Я мог, конечно, каждому объекту присвоить не только Bitmap, но и оттенок. А потом рисовать каждый объект 2 раза. Сначала картинку, а потом цвет с прозрачностью. Но это приведёт к удвоению вычислений

Comment: Нагрузка на процессор сразу увеличится как минимум в 2 раза!!! Поэтому мне бы хотелось смешать картинку и цвет заранее, на стадии загрузки. А потом быстро и без нагрузки на процессор выводить на экран одно изображение